# Image is not getting loaded in release apk by using Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

While building release APK getting following warning `Warning:com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BitmapCounterProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.infer.annotation.ThreadSafe`

I supressed it by using progard-rules.

```
-dontwarn com.facebook.infer.annotation.ThreadSafe
```

Does this issue concerned with image loading in release apk?

Comment: I found its solution from https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1973, thanks to dmitry-voronkevich

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will be useful for others,
http://frescolib.org/docs/shipping.html#proguard here they provided proguard-fresco.pro file which is required to be included in build.gradle file

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-fresco.pro'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Was facing an error while trying to compile fresco from source for release. Adding `proguard-fresco.pro` to release `proguardFiles` fixed the issue and compiled. +1